# How to include all subfolder and files

Tags: yocto

In yocto recipe, we use

```
 FILES_${PN} += "foo"
```

to include files.

How about I want to include all subfolders and files. How to assign it?

I don't want to do this:

```
FILE_$(PN} +="foo foo/* foo/*/* foo/*/*/* ......"
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
variable +="\` find foo | xargs `"
```

There may need to be "no spaces" or a "single space" on either side of the `+=` depending on the flavor of UNIX you are using.

Comment: Why the pipe to `xargs`?

Comment: To put the output all onto 1 line separated by spaces instead of on separate lines.  In some contexts of use, this is done automatically so you might check if you need to specify xargs explicitly here.  (If the maximum number of xargs arguments is exceeded, it sometimes works with 'xargs -n3333333' i.e. with some number larger than the default maximum number of xargs arguments.)  (Just noticed the extra \ in the rendering above)

Comment: In that case, you could just use `tr '\n' ' '`. You should probably also say something about files with whitespace characters in their names...

Comment: I forgot about white spaces.  Personally I avoid whitespace in file names, but I forgot that  such is not generally the case.

Comment: Sometimes you can't avoid them. On a macOS system, you will find several directory names in `~/Library` containing spaces, e.g. `Keyboard Layouts`, `Input Methods` and `Saved Application State`.

Comment: Generally I have not had to deal with OS related files, only files of my own making or Downloaded datafiles that I rename to lose the space as I download.  The syntax with quotation marks or backslashes before can get tricky and be context dependent.  Have dealt with on occasion using sed & awk, but they are really application dependent and I deal with them on a case-by-case basis.  Don't know about the specifics for the case above.

Comment: I don't know what `yocto` is, but in a `bash` shell script I would suggest using an array instead: `files=( foo/**/* )` (with the `globstar`, `nullglob`, and `dotglob` shell options set).